# What are the rules of capitalization and article usage with building names?

Tags: articles, capitalization

What are the rules for building names? In particular, does the word "building" need to be capitalized when a part of a building's name? How about article "the" - what are the rules for using it as a part of the name, and does it get capitalized in the middle of the sentence? For instance: is it "the American Radiator building" or "The American Radiator Building" or "American Radiator building"? How about when the address is the name of the building, like 7 World Trade Center?

Answer (score 4):

Building names are proper nouns. The given (or official) name of the structure you mentioned is "[American Radiator Building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Radiator_Building)"*. Thus, "Building" should always be capitalized in this name. On the other hand, *the* is not part of the given name. So, in this sentence:

```
I visited the American Radiator Building yesterday
```

it would be incorrect to capitalize *the* thus:

```
I visited The American Radiator Building yesterday
```

When writing an address, the official name of the building should always be used. It follows that all the words in that name should be capitalized. Your example,

```
 7 World Trade Center
```

is correct. One might also see/hear "World Trade Center" used within a sentence, for instance:

```
Memories of the tragedy at the World Trade Center remain fresh in our hearts.
```

It would be wrong to capitalize *the* in the above example, based on the aforementioned reason.

**Interesting note: Though still widely referred to by its old name, "American Radiator Building" was officially renamed "American Standard Building".*

Comment: @RegDwight: Ah, right you are! My bad. Edited to fix that. Thanks for pointing out.