# Capitalization rules for "the"

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalising the definite article in names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/capitalising-the-definite-article-in-names)

I'm a bit confused on the proper capitalization rules when "the" is part of someone's title. For example, if I have a character referred to as "The Blacksmith", which of these sentences would be correct?

> In an era long gone by, there existed an entity known as The Blacksmith.

or

> In an era long gone by, there existed an entity known as the Blacksmith.

Comment: Welcome! I think MetaEd's answer in [Capitalising the definite article in names](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/capitalising-the-definite-article-in-names) probably covers it.

Comment: Thanks, the answer to that question proved to be very helpful!