# When writing a title, do you capitalize "the" in names like "Boris The Animal"?

Tags: grammar, capitalization, titles

When writing a title, do you capitalize "the" in names like "Boris The Animal", "Mike the Bike Guy" or "Tom The Dancing Bug"?

Comment: related [Capitalising the definite article](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/capitalising-the-definite-article-in-names)

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

In normal usage I would say not, but I suppose I should mention that -- for reasons best known to themselves -- quite a few American newspapers like to give initial capitals to every single word in a headline.

Comment: Newspapers in the US usually follow a style manual, I think one of the more famous ones being [Chicago Style Manual](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html), and [MLA](http://library.concordia.ca/help/howto/mla.php). As for book titles, I'm sure each house follows their own criteria, and if one is only writing the title to a story for homework then anything goes, I guess.