# Would I use 'The FA' or 'the FA' in a sentence?

Tags: capitalization, names, acronyms

I'm writing a sentence that refers to The Football Association and want to shorten it to the FA, but I'm unsure whether I should capitalise the T in 'the' or not because its official name is The Football Association.

If I capitalise the T, it looks strange to me, however on their own website they do capitalise it (e.g. 'view the latest financial statements of The FA').

So if I were to write a sentence like 'please refer to the FA website', would the T be capitalised or not?

Comment: In your sentence, "the" doesn't modify "FA", it modifies "website", so it should be small. If you want to include a capitalized "The", you would have to write "to the website of The FA" or "to The FA's website" (since "to the The FA website" doesn't work at all).

Comment: @PeterShor: Arguably the "The" should be lowercase even in the form "the website of [The or the] FA." The FA website itself is inconsistent on this point: its [Who We Are](http://www.thefa.com/about-football-association/who-we-are) page includes consecutive captions that say, respectively, "**Senior Management Team** Working with The FA Board, Council and staff" and "**The FA Board and Committee** Full details of the FA Board and Committee." I suppose the key question to answer is whether "The FA" is more like "The Hague" or "the United Nations."

Comment: @SvenYargs: the website seems generally not to capitalize *The* when FA is used as an adjective, as in *"Match-fixing, or breaching the FA betting rules, or using inside information, is serious stuff."* It generally does when it's used as a noun in the middle of a sentence, as in *"involved in fixing, then you must report it to The FA immediately."* So I suspect *"with The FA Board"* is an error (it's quite hard to keep this distinction straight, so it's completely understandable.)

Comment: @PeterShor Articles would only be capitalized in actual titles of songs, books, plays, etc., but never otherwise. So the team is just the Yankees and such, never *The Yankees. This has become so frighteningly common a mistake that I wonder how it is that kids are no longer taught how to read and write English.

Comment: @tchrist the Yankees' full name is just 'Yankees' though, so I can see why 'the' would be lower case. With The Football Association, however, the 'the' is actually part of its name (on its logo it says 'The FA').

Comment: @SFraser You can't judge name from a logo. Logos are just stylistic representations. You have to go by official text. In this case, the website itself is entirely inconsistent. In the case of **the White House**, *the* is not part of the name itself, and is only capitalized when it's the first word in a sentence. But in the case of **The Boss** (Bruce Springsteen), **The** ***is*** part of his nickname and it's *always* capitalized, regardless of where it's located in a sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalisation in texts where the title is also a concept that is referred to within the text?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500978/capitalisation-in-texts-where-the-title-is-also-a-concept-that-is-referred-to-wi)