# Article before newspaper name

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

Suppose the name of a newspaper is *Pirate Times*, without an article. Which of the following is then correct, and why?

> - During the recent General Assembly, Pirate Times met…
> - During the recent General Assembly, **the** Pirate Times met…

Is there a general rule for the use of articles before newspaper name?

Comment: And then, what if the name of the newspaper is in another language?  .... "I read this in the *Diario El Sol*"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

House style prevails. How does the organization refer to itself? Do they provide identity guidelines for third party media? Nearly all newspapers take *the*, but there are as many exceptions as there are rules when it comes to applying articles to named entities.

---

Certainly, if it is part of the official name, it would always be included except where attributive: *The New York Times*, *The Telegraph*; but *New York Times columnist Thomas Friedman* and *Telegraph motorcycle correspondent Kevin Ash*.

In other cases, the article is not part of the official name, but it gets attached idiomatically: *She writes for the Chicago Tribune*, *I subscribe to the South China Morning Post*. Perhaps this is because many publication names are based around a common noun, and we naturally add *the* to most such names: *The Wall Street Journal*, not merely any Wall Street journal, same as the Royal Society, the University of Virginia, the Brisbane Lions, or the Socialist Republic of Vietnam.

Newspaper names not based on this formula (the *Foo Newspapertype*) do not accept articles: *Barron's*, never *the Barron's*, as with *Roll Call*, *USA Today*, *Stars and Stripes*, and so on.

But then there's *Sporting News*, never *the Sporting News*, because that is their house style. And *JAMA* is always simply *JAMA*, even though the full, official name is *JAMA: The Journal of the American Medical Association*.

See also

- [Use of definite article before phrases like Heathrow Airport, Hyde Park, Waterloo Station, Edgware Road and Parliament Square](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34704/use-of-definite-article-before-phrases-like-heathrow-airport-hyde-park-waterlo)
- [Definite article before schools, colleges, and universities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/definite-article-before-schools-colleges-and-universities)
- [What are the rules of capitalization and article usage with building names?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7007/what-are-the-rules-of-capitalization-and-article-usage-with-building-names)
- [Use of article in front of product names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77074/use-of-article-in-front-of-product-names)
- [Using the definite article before a country/state name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)

Comment: "The Express" is normal in Britain, where it means "The Daily Express". Not disagreeing with your point, but for that reason, _I saw it in Express_ reads very oddly to me.

Comment: @ColinFine I was thinking of [a different *Express*](http://www.expressnightout.com/), but this neatly illustrates my point about house styles :). I used a different example.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option A. It's the same rule as a company name. "..the Nike released a new running shoe" doesn't sound correct. If the newspaper is called "The Pirate Times", then obviously the second option is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Only when the definite article *the* is the part of the newspaper title, must you use it.

For example, in India there are many English newspapers with *the* as part of their names:

- ***The** Hindu*
- ***The** Indian Express*
- ***The** Times of India*

If no *the* comes before the name of a newspaper, there is no need to add it.

In Kerala, a state of India, there are many Malayalam newspapers none of which has a leading *the* in its name:

- *Malayala Manorama*
- *Mathrubhumi*
- *Madhyamam*

For example:

> - I regularly read ***The** Hindu* to improve my English.
> - Are you a regular reader of *Malayala Manorama*?

Answer (score -1):

Let us change the name in your question:

> Suppose the name of a <s>newspaper</s> **person** is <s>Pirate Times</s> **John**, without an article. Which of the following is then correct, and why?

During the recent General Assembly, **John** met…

During the recent General Assembly, **the John** met…